# Slack blocks for message formatting

Tags: slack

I am having hard time formatting my message layout using slack api block elements. I need to have a text, an image and a button all on the same line. I couldn't find a way to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the interactive message builder: https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder

Answer (score 1):

I emailed slack and according to them, there is currently no way to have a text, an image and a button all on the same line. You can't do that with block-kit builder